# Property 'loadDataTimerID' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent' in Angular

Tags: angular

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  posts:Post[];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPosts()
    this.loadDataTimerID = setInterval(this.loadPosts, 3000);
  }

  loadPosts = () => {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => {
      if (this.loadDataTimerID) {
        clearInterval(this.loadDataTimerID);
      }
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }

}
```

Code is working fine - data is loading every 3 seconds and `this.loadDataTimerID` is removed if there is the data in the response.
But for some reason I see an error in my terminal:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/home/home.component.ts(15,10): error TS2339: Property 'loadDataTimerID' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal javascript you can enter not existing fields using this on an object. But typescript doesnt let it to happen so gives you error while compiling what you should do is that add field decleration at the beginning of class as:

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit{
  loadDataTimerID : any;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

By this way it Typescript wont be upset when you compile and it will work since type any gets type of assigned object.